# Javascript not working for IOS 16.3.1 and lower

Tags: javascript, ios, dom-events

I have javascript code on my web page, It works for desktop, android,
However it's not working for some iPhones, each part of my code, input events, click event

**Works for this iPhone models and versions:**

1. Iphone 13 safari version 16.6
2. Iphone 12 safari version 16.6
3. Iphone 13 safari version 16.5.1
4. Iphone 11 safari version 16.5

**But my code doesn't work for this types of iPhone:**

1. Iphone 11  safari version 16.1
2. Iphone 11 safari version 16.3.1
3. Iphone  XS Max safari version 16.5.1
4. Iphone  Xr  safari version 16.5.1
5. Iphone XR safari version 16.3.1

**This is my code:**

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    const header = document.querySelector(".header");
    const langSelect = document.querySelector("#lang_select");
    const langList = document.querySelector(".lang_list");

    header.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
      langList.style.display = langList.style.display === "none" ? "block" : "none";
      event.stopPropagation();
    });

    document.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
      if (!langSelect.contains(event.target)) {
        langList.style.display = "none";
      }
    });

    const fieldInputs = document.querySelectorAll(".field input");

fieldInputs.forEach(function(input) {
  input.addEventListener("focus", function() {
    this.parentElement.classList.add("active");
  });

  input.addEventListener("blur", function() {
    if (this.value === "") {
      this.parentElement.classList.remove("active");
    }
  });
});

let isFirstOpen = false;
  const firstBtn = document.querySelector("#firstBtn");
  const firstDrop = document.querySelector("#firstDrop");

  firstBtn.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    isFirstOpen = !isFirstOpen;

    if (isFirstOpen) {
      firstDrop.style.display = "block";
    } else {
      firstDrop.style.display = "none";
    }

    event.stopPropagation();
  });

  document.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  if (
    !event.target.closest("#firstBtn") &&
    !event.target.closest("#firstDrop")
  ) {
    const firstDropElement = document.querySelector("#firstDrop");
    if (firstDropElement.style.display !== "none") {
      firstDropElement.style.display = "none";
      isFirstOpen = false;
    }
  }
});

  



 

      

  document.querySelector("#firstInput input").addEventListener("input", function() {
  const inputVal = this.value;
  let num = inputVal.replace(/[^0-9.]+/g, "");
  let regex = /^[+-]?(\d*\.\d+|\d+\.\d*)([eE][+-]?\d+)?$/;

  if (!regex.test(num)) {
    if (num === ".") {
      num = "";
    } else {
      num = num.replace(/(?<=\..*)\./, "");
    }
  }

  this.value = num;

  const firstCryptoCurrencySymbol = document.querySelector("#currency1 a").dataset.cur;
  const secondCryptoCurrencySymbol = document.querySelector("#currency2 a").dataset.cur;

  fetch("/calculateExchangeRate", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      firstCryptoCurrencySymbol: firstCryptoCurrencySymbol,
      secondCryptoCurrencySymbol: secondCryptoCurrencySymbol
    })
  })
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => {
    const exchangeRate = data.rate;
    document.querySelector("#secondInput input").value = num * exchangeRate;
  });
});



document.querySelector("#secondInput input").addEventListener("input", function() {
  const inputVal = this.value;
  let num = inputVal.replace(/[^0-9.]+/g, "");
  let regex = /^[+-]?(\d*\.\d+|\d+\.\d*)([eE][+-]?\d+)?$/;

  if (!regex.test(num)) {
    if (num === ".") {
      num = "";
    } else {
      num = num.replace(/(?<=\..*)\./, "");
    }
  }

  this.value = num;

  const firstCryptoCurrencySymbol = document.querySelector("#currency1 a").dataset.cur;
  const secondCryptoCurrencySymbol = document.querySelector("#currency2 a").dataset.cur;

  fetch("/calculateExchangeRate", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      firstCryptoCurrencySymbol: firstCryptoCurrencySymbol,
      secondCryptoCurrencySymbol: secondCryptoCurrencySymbol
    })
  })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
      const exchangeRate = data.rate;
      document.querySelector("#firstInput input").value = num / exchangeRate;
    });
});




         
const optionElements = document.querySelectorAll(".option");

optionElements.forEach(function(option) {
  option.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    if ('ontouchstart' in window || navigator.maxTouchPoints) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }

    let dataCur = this.dataset.cur;
    let imageUrl = this.querySelector(".pm_select_img img").src;
    let optionText = this.querySelector("span").textContent;

    document.querySelector("#firstBtn .pm_select_img img").src = imageUrl;
    document.querySelector("#firstBtn span").textContent = optionText;
    document.querySelector("#firstBtn").dataset.cur = dataCur;

    document.querySelector("#currency1 .pm_select_child").dataset.cur = dataCur;
    document.querySelector("#currency1 .pm_select_child").textContent = dataCur;

    document.querySelector("#hiddenInput").value = dataCur;

    document.querySelector("#amount_send1").dataset.cur = dataCur;
    document.querySelector("#amount_send1 ~ .addons").textContent = dataCur;

    const secondDataCur = document.querySelector("#currency2 a").dataset.cur;

    fetch("/calculateExchangeRate", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        firstCryptoCurrencySymbol: dataCur,
        secondCryptoCurrencySymbol: secondDataCur
      })
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
      const exchangeRate = data.rate;
      document.querySelector(".rate_info").textContent = `1 ${dataCur} = ${exchangeRate} ${secondDataCur}`;
    });

   
    event.stopPropagation();
  });
});

document.addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.querySelector("#firstDrop").style.display = "none";
});



const optionElementsFirst = document.querySelectorAll(".option1");

optionElementsFirst.forEach(function (option) {
  option.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    if ("ontouchstart" in window || navigator.maxTouchPoints) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }

    let dataCur = this.dataset.cur;
    let imageUrl = this.querySelector(".pm_select_img img").src;
    let optionText = this.querySelector("span").textContent;

    document.querySelector("#secondBtn .pm_select_img img").src = imageUrl;
    document.querySelector("#secondBtn span").textContent = optionText;
    document.querySelector("#secondBtn").dataset.cur = dataCur;

    document.querySelector("#currency2 .pm_select_child").dataset.cur = dataCur;
    document.querySelector("#currency2 .pm_select_child").textContent = dataCur;

    document.querySelector("#hiddenInput2").value = dataCur;

    document.querySelector("#amount_send2").dataset.cur = dataCur;
    document.querySelector("#amount_send2 ~ .addons").textContent = dataCur;

    const secondDataCur = document.querySelector("#currency1 a").dataset.cur;

    fetch("/calculateExchangeRate", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        firstCryptoCurrencySymbol: dataCur,
        secondCryptoCurrencySymbol: secondDataCur,
      }),
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        const exchangeRate = data.rate;
        document.querySelector(".rate_info").textContent = `1 ${dataCur} = ${exchangeRate} ${secondDataCur}`;
      });

    document.querySelector("#secondDrop").style.display = "none";

    
    event.stopPropagation();
  });
});

document.addEventListener("click", function () {
  document.querySelector("#secondDrop").style.display = "none";
});


let isOpen = false;
const secondBtn = document.querySelector("#secondBtn");
const secondDrop = document.querySelector("#secondDrop");

secondBtn.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  isOpen = !isOpen;

  if (isOpen) {
    secondDrop.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    secondDrop.style.display = "none";
  }

  event.stopPropagation();
});


document.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  const secondBtn = document.querySelector("#secondBtn");
  const secondDrop = document.querySelector("#secondDrop");
  const isOpen = secondDrop.style.display !== "none";

  if (
    !event.target.closest("#secondBtn") &&
    !event.target.closest("#secondDrop")
  ) {
    if (isOpen) {
      secondDrop.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
});


  })
```

- I was checking if I have syntax errors but, I don't have any
- I  was thinking that  I use some advanced functions and I remade my code with bubble but it didn't helped
- I was thinking that there is issue with click event so I added ever touch event but it didn't helped
- I tried using simulation on Mac, but in them code worked perfectly
- I used simulation in browser stack and there were my problems

Comment: Welcome! You gave us a **HUGE** code dump, and say "it's not working". What's not working? What is the specific issue? Do you have any errors in your web browser console? The code may run in browsers if there are certain errors, but not on a mobile device. Please read [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Give us a smaller portion of the code...and maybe some HTML, so we can actually test this.

Comment: Have you tried disabling code and running it. And keeping on doing that until you don't get the error?

Comment: It's probably the [lookbehinds in your regexes](https://caniuse.com/?search=lookbehind)